# How to call the row in a matrix after certain criteria has been met?

Tags: r, matrix, subset

I have a matrix called total_warnings

```
     row day  Tx    Hx   Tn
36   36   5 32.5 37.78 16.3
41   41  10 33.3 41.46 20.5
42   42  11 31.7 41.57 21.2
43   43  12 31.3 39.03 22.2
45   45  14 29.1 37.34 19.0
55   55  24 33.7 41.77 16.4
56   56  25 29.3 38.07 15.9
58   58  27 35.0 41.07 15.3
59   59  28 34.3 40.37 18.5
61   61  30 33.5 40.34 14.9
65   65   4 31.0 37.24 11.4
72   72  11 32.6 40.00 16.2
73   73  12 33.8 40.25 16.8
74   74  13 34.7 41.04 18.6
76   76  15 31.4 39.47 18.4
77   77  16 27.7 37.30 18.4
78   78  17 27.9 38.36 22.3
79   79  18 32.9 42.07 20.1
82   82  21 32.0 38.62 19.3
93   93   1 28.6 37.55 18.1 
94   94   2 30.3 39.71 15.3
95   95   3 32.7 39.46 17.5
101 101   9 33.0 39.00 17.4
104 104  12 27.5 37.10 16.7
135 135  12 32.6 38.45 17.7
```

What I'm attempting to do is indentify the contents of the row ONE AFTER three or more consecutive rows. For example 41, 42, 43 are three consecutive rows, I would like to call the contents of row 45!

```
45  14 29.1 37.34 19.0
```

So for this example rows 45, 82, 101 would be returned. If the row after the three or more consecutive rows is part of another set of TWO or more consecutive rows I DO NOT need to know the contents. For example 72, 73, 74 is a set but I do not want row 76 because it is part of another set 76, 77, 78, 79!

Thanks for the help in advance!
Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rle` function (run length encoding) can be combined with the `diff` function to identify the locations where the differences are  1 and have length greater than or equal to 2. The diff-operation actually shifts the names by 1 so there's no need to add 1 to the `names()`-result. That character result can then be used to index a matrix with rownames:

```
> rle( diff(mat[,'row']))
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: Named int [1:19] 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:19] "42" "45" "55" "56" ...
  values : Named num [1:19] 5 1 2 10 1 2 1 2 4 7 ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:19] "41" "43" "45" "55" ...
> rdiffs <- rle( diff(mat[,'row']))
> rdiffs$lengths >= 2
   42    45    55    56    58    59    61    65    72    73    76    77 
FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE 
   82    93    94   101   104   135       
 TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE 

> attr(rdiffs$lengths,"names")[ rdiffs$lengths >= 2 ]
[1] "45"  "76"  "82"  "101"

> mat [ attr(rdiffs$lengths,"names")[ rdiffs$lengths >= 2 & rdiffs$values == 1] , ]
    row day   Tx    Hx   Tn
45   45  14 29.1 37.34 19.0
76   76  15 31.4 39.47 18.4
82   82  21 32.0 38.62 19.3
101 101   9 33.0 39.00 17.4
```

I'll also put in a reproducible example:

```
dn <- scan()
36   36   5 32.5 37.78 16.3
41   41  10 33.3 41.46 20.5
42   42  11 31.7 41.57 21.2
43   43  12 31.3 39.03 22.2
45   45  14 29.1 37.34 19.0
55   55  24 33.7 41.77 16.4
56   56  25 29.3 38.07 15.9
58   58  27 35.0 41.07 15.3
59   59  28 34.3 40.37 18.5
61   61  30 33.5 40.34 14.9
65   65   4 31.0 37.24 11.4
72   72  11 32.6 40.00 16.2
73   73  12 33.8 40.25 16.8
74   74  13 34.7 41.04 18.6
76   76  15 31.4 39.47 18.4
77   77  16 27.7 37.30 18.4
78   78  17 27.9 38.36 22.3
79   79  18 32.9 42.07 20.1
82   82  21 32.0 38.62 19.3
93   93   1 28.6 37.55 18.1 
94   94   2 30.3 39.71 15.3
95   95   3 32.7 39.46 17.5
101 101   9 33.0 39.00 17.4
104 104  12 27.5 37.10 16.7
135 135  12 32.6 38.45 17.7
mat <- matrix(dn, ncol=6, byrow=TRUE)
mat<- mat[, -1]
colnames(mat) <- c('row', 'day',  'Tx',    'Hx',   'Tn')
rownames(mat) <-mat[,'row']
```

Comment: Yep, I certainly did miss the extra exclusionary clause about not wanting adjacent sequences. So many exclamation points must have rattled my concentration.